# Debian 10 - iwlwifi Problem (iwlwifi-7265d)

Tags: linux, debian, iwlwifi

I have a weird problem with my Thinkpad x250 and its Intel 7265D Wifi card on Debian 10 running a 4.19.0-9 kernel. And would be thankful for any help!

Wifi works after a fresh boot and the first connect. As soon as i want to change the network, disable wifi or loose the connection iam unable to reconnect to any network without a reboot.
This also prevents me from using standby or hibernation mode.

What i tried:

- moved /lib/fimrware/iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode to force loading an older firmware → no effect
- when wifi stops working: `mmod iwlmvm && sleep 2 && rmmod iwlwifi && modprobe iwlwifi && modprobe iwlmvm` → no effect
- looked for other firmware modules on the intel website → the neweset version that can be found there there (7265-14) is older than the ones, that are tried to load by my system

```
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494614] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494630] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494643] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494654] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494665] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494678] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494691] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494702] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode failed with error -2
```

Interesting:

- as soon as wifi stops working, any wifi related action in NetworkManager-GUI leads to the service hanging up. Running `systemctl NetworkManager restart`does not even complete and gives no useful output.

Output of `grep iwlwifi /var/log/messages`

```
Jun 14 07:36:35 uutnb01 kernel: [ 8730.854200] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 14 07:36:35 uutnb01 kernel: [ 8730.854612] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 14 07:36:35 uutnb01 kernel: [ 8730.870619] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 14 07:36:35 uutnb01 kernel: [ 8730.894600] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 14 07:36:35 uutnb01 kernel: [ 8730.963989] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 14 07:36:45 uutnb01 NetworkManager[17530]: <info>  [1592113005.2891] rfkill7: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy3/rfkill7) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 14 10:10:13 uutnb01 kernel: [17948.213234] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 14 10:10:13 uutnb01 kernel: [17948.213517] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 14 10:10:13 uutnb01 kernel: [17948.233131] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 14 10:10:13 uutnb01 kernel: [17948.258804] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 14 10:10:13 uutnb01 kernel: [17948.335047] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 14 10:11:46 uutnb01 NetworkManager[2203]: <info>  [1592122306.7484] rfkill8: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy4/rfkill8) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 14 10:11:47 uutnb01 kernel: [18041.622553] Modules linked in: e1000e iwlmvm iwlwifi ctr ccm rfcomm fuse xfrm_user xfrm4_tunnel tunnel4 ipcomp xfrm_ipcomp esp4 ah4 af_key xfrm_algo vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) tun overlay cmac bnep xt_conntrack nft_counter nft_chain_nat_ipv4 ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink squashfs zstd_decompress xxhash loop mei_wdt intel_rapl cdc_mbim cdc_ncm r8188eu(C) btusb x86_pkg_temp_thermal btrtl btbcm intel_powerclamp btintel uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc coretemp videobuf2_memops usbnet videobuf2_v4l2 mii bluetooth lib80211 videobuf2_common cdc_acm cdc_wdm videodev kvm_intel media drbg ansi_cprng arc4 joydev kvm ecdh_generic irqbypass intel_cstate snd_hda_codec_realtek mac80211 snd_hda_codec_generic
Jun 14 23:45:21 uutnb01 kernel: [66855.566032] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 20 12:13:24 uutnb01 kernel: [66857.888921] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Jun 20 12:44:22 uutnb01 kernel: [68717.281078] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 22 08:57:49 uutnb01 kernel: [68718.987016] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 kernel: [   17.251428] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 kernel: [   17.251753] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 kernel: [   17.381977] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 kernel: [   17.403348] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 kernel: [   17.926913] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 22 09:01:27 uutnb01 NetworkManager[1400]: <info>  [1592809287.5704] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 22 20:38:00 uutnb01 kernel: [41811.112040] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 07:38:30 uutnb01 kernel: [   13.108422] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 07:38:30 uutnb01 kernel: [   13.108791] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 07:38:30 uutnb01 kernel: [   13.233637] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 07:38:30 uutnb01 kernel: [   13.257343] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 07:38:30 uutnb01 kernel: [   13.529670] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 07:38:31 uutnb01 NetworkManager[1357]: <info>  [1592890711.0943] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 23 08:33:05 uutnb01 kernel: [ 3289.316897] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 19:45:08 uutnb01 kernel: [ 3291.087792] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 kernel: [   22.831011] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 kernel: [   22.831408] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 kernel: [   22.938907] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 kernel: [   22.972899] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 kernel: [   23.330156] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 19:48:02 uutnb01 NetworkManager[1389]: <info>  [1592934482.5204] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 23 19:55:50 uutnb01 kernel: [  492.724299] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 19:55:50 uutnb01 kernel: [  492.724576] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 19:55:50 uutnb01 kernel: [  492.740767] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 19:55:50 uutnb01 kernel: [  492.764675] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 19:55:50 uutnb01 kernel: [  492.834589] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 kernel: [   12.266399] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 kernel: [   12.266874] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 kernel: [   12.388706] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 kernel: [   12.427583] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 kernel: [   12.956799] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:09:36 uutnb01 NetworkManager[1404]: <info>  [1592935776.5417] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 23 20:12:29 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.319048] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
Jun 23 20:12:29 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.319498] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1044073957.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:12:29 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.334058] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:12:29 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.356987] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:12:30 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.427244] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:12:30 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.655957] Modules linked in: iwlmvm iwlwifi rfcomm fuse xfrm_user xfrm4_tunnel tunnel4 ipcomp xfrm_ipcomp esp4 ah4 af_key xfrm_algo ctr ccm vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) overlay tun cmac bnep xt_conntrack nft_counter nft_chain_nat_ipv4 ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c xt_addrtype nft_compat nf_tables nfnetlink joydev btusb btrtl btbcm squashfs zstd_decompress mei_wdt xxhash btintel loop uvcvideo bluetooth videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_common intel_rapl cdc_mbim arc4 videodev drbg ansi_cprng media cdc_ncm usbnet ecdh_generic mii cdc_acm cdc_wdm x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic mac80211 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_hda_codec
Jun 23 20:12:30 uutnb01 kernel: [  188.655995]  rtsx_pci e1000e(-) lpc_ich usb_common mfd_core thermal wmi video button [last unloaded: iwlwifi]
Jun 23 20:14:02 uutnb01 NetworkManager[18509]: <info>  [1592936042.9225] rfkill4: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy1/rfkill4) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050351] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050359] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050370] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050376] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050383] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050389] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050396] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:16:15 uutnb01 kernel: [  414.050402] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494614] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494630] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494643] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494654] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494665] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494678] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494691] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:17:42 uutnb01 kernel: [   15.494702] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096396] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096413] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096425] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096437] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096449] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096461] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.096473] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.100080] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.100448] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.244459] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.272311] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 kernel: [   25.620655] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:21:39 uutnb01 NetworkManager[1386]: <info>  [1592936499.5341] rfkill2: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill2) (driver iwlwifi)
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414551] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414559] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414565] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414571] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414576] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414582] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414587] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.414926] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.415334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.433387] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.458030] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:24:21 uutnb01 kernel: [  189.526491] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335044] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335052] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335059] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335065] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335071] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335078] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335083] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335422] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.335759] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.359898] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.385276] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:24:45 uutnb01 kernel: [  213.458788] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787135] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787143] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787150] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787158] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787167] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787175] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787184] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.787601] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.788091] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.811477] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.835252] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:24:56 uutnb01 kernel: [  223.903400] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617910] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617923] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-28.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617934] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617944] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-26.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-25.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617963] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.617973] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.618376] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.618818] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.391740.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.635581] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
Jun 23 20:25:18 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.660065] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Jun 23 20:25:19 uutnb01 kernel: [  246.725612] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
Jun 23 20:25:54 uutnb01 NetworkManager[18495]: <info>  [1592936754.9910] rfkill7: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/phy4/rfkill7) (driver iwlwifi)
```